# How to remove actionscript (ABC) from SWF?

Tags: actionscript, flash

We are loading external SWFs that serve as graphic assets. How do we remove ABC inside these SWFs (if any)?

It will be good if this can be done on server side like python or php.

This link provides some info to modify, but not removing ABC in its entirety:
[Is it possible to remove actionScript from inside of SWF file using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911230/is-it-possible-to-remove-actionscript-from-inside-of-swf-file-using-php)

Comment: What do you mean by ABC?

Comment: Actionscript Bytecode